# writing batch file to copy files from one folder and sending them to another

Tags: windows-vista

I need to know the code for a batch file, to copy files from one folder on my C drive, to another.

- Must copy folder structure
- Must copy attributes of files
- Must copy hidden files and directories
- Must not require any user input beyond source and destination paths
- Must use a system of variables to contain the paths
- Must log copy process

Answer (score 0):

Following command should work:

```
xcopy /E /L /H /K /O <src> <dest>
```

Comment: You mentioned it in your answer here then why did you leave the same comment on the question itself?

Comment: @ryanwolf - You have to replace <src> and <dest> with original values.  For instance,  xcopy /E /L /H /K /O C:\foo C:\bar.

Comment: i entered in the values but the files arent copied to the destination